# Parsing Json specific field from Response in Android

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "cookie":"dr.steve|akscjn",
    "cookie_name":"wordpress_logged_in",
    "user": {
        "id":330,
        "username":"dr.steve",
        "nicename":"steve",
        "email":"steve@docdirect.com",
        "url":"http:\/\/www.company.com",
        "registered":"2016-12-15 22:21:05",
        "displayname":"Dr.Steve",
        "firstname":"Dr",
        "lastname":"Steve",
        "nickname":"steve",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum",
        "capabilities":"",
        "avatar":null
    }
}
```

I have this json response and i want the only id field from this json , I think there are two nested arrays but i am geting error

**E/Error: Json parsing error: Value {"id":330,.........}at user of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray**

this my code

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {

                        JSONArray ja = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONArray("user");
                        JSONObject c =  ja.getJSONObject(1);
                        String id = c.getString("id");

                        temp2 = id;

                        Log.v("id---->",temp2);

                      }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("Error", "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
```

can anyone tell where i am making a mistake how would i get id field from this json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user` property is a concrete object not an array so try to read it as an object:

```
JSONObject user = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

`"user":{` is  an object.

Arrays have square brackets. You have no arrays in your data